# $F_n(x) \to G(x)$ weakly if and only if $F_n(x) \to G(x)$ for all $x$ that is continuity point of $G$ and $0<G(x)<1$?

Tags: distributions, convergence

If $F_n$, $G$($G$ is non-degenerate) are distribution functions in $\mathbb{R}$, is the fact that $F_n \to G$ weakly($F_n(x) \to G(x)$ for all continuity point of $G$) equivalent to the condition that $F_n(x) \to G(x)$ for all $x$ that is continuity point of $G$ and $0<G(x)<1$?

Context is that one of the implicit claim in my textbook is that for $a_n > 0$, $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$, $F^n(a_n x +b_n) \to G(x)$ for every continuity point of $G$ is equivalent to the condition that $n \log F(a_n x + b_n) \to G(x)$ for every continuity point of $G$ with $0<x<1$. This condition is of course equivalent to $F^n(a_n x + b_n) \to G(x)$ for all continuity point of $G$ with $0<x<1$.

[image]

[image]

If $G$ has no jump discontinuity, I believe the claim follows. But if $G$ has jump discontinuity so that for $x_0$, $G(x_0) = 1$ but $G(x) = 1$ for $x<x_0$, or for $y_0$, $G(y_0) > 0$ but $G(x) = 0$ for $x<y_0$, I do not know how to see the equivalence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this equivalence obviously does not hold. For example, let
\begin{align}
& G(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0, \\
1/2 & 0 \leq x < 1, \\
1 & x \geq 1.
\end{cases} \\
& F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < -1, \\
1/4 & -1 \leq x < 0, \\
1/2 & 0 \leq x < 1, \\
1 & x \geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{align}
And let $F_n \equiv F$.  Since $F_n(x) \equiv G(x)$ for all $x$ such that $0 < G(x) < 1$ and $G$ is continuous, the latter condition is met.  However, $F_n$ of course does not converge to $G$ weakly.

Comment: Based on questions you have been asking before, it is unsurprising for me to see claims made by this author that are over-strong or very hard to verify. Probably it is not a very well-written book from the pure math point of view.

Comment: it's a different book this time, Extreme Value Theory: An Introduction by Haan. The book seems to be the canonical one for EVT.

Comment: This analysis doesn't address the question, where $F^n$ is the $n^\text{th}$ *power* of $F.$

Comment: @whuber It answers OP's general question in the very first paragraph (and the title) of his post.  In fact, you can view $F^n$ in the screenshot as $F_n$ in OP's own question or my answer.

Comment: My interpretation is that the "general question" does not accurately reflect the textbook passage that prompted it.  So, I am suggesting that a potentially more helpful response would be to clarify that point and address the claim made in the textbook, rather than suggesting the textbook might be poorly written.

Comment: @whuber. Before writing this answer, I took time reading the textbook screenshot, and found that it is literally no different from OP's general question (this is also observed by OP in his second paragraph).  If you have some way to show the claim made in the text is "provable", I am looking forward to see your written answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only claim made in the screenshot ensues from the continuity of the logarithm on the domain $(0,1).$